# int16 to byte array

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert a int16 to a byte array but i cant seem to get it to work.
Here is what i've got right now:

```
int16 i := 41
a := []byte(string(i))//this line is wrong
```

Also if someone wonder the array needs to be a length of 2.

Comment: Do you want the individual bytes of the int16?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to get the bytes of an int16, try something like this:

```
var i int16 = 41
var h, l uint8 = uint8(i>>8), uint8(i&0xff)
```

Go tries to make it difficult to write programs that depend on attributes of your platform such as byte order. Thence, type punning that leads to such dependencies (such as overlaying a byte-array with an int16) is forbidden.

In case you really want to shoot yourself in the foot, try the package [unsafe](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe).

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!! :D
And sorry but i cant wote you answer because i dont have 15 points yet..

Comment: @Max No problem. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 54):

While FUZxxl's answer works, you can also use the encoding/binary package:

```
var i int16 = 41
b := make([]byte, 2)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b, uint16(i))
```

The encoding/binary package has prebuilt functions for encoding little and big endian for all fixed size integers and some easy to use functions if you are using Readers and Writers instead of byte slices. Example:

```
var i int16 = 41
err := binary.Write(w, binary.LittleEndian, i)
```

Comment: Isn't this going to be a lot slower than simply shifting two bytes to form an uint16?

Comment: @fuz "Simply shifting ... bytes" is exactly what those functions do, so the compiler has the option of inlining that operation if it wants to.  Essentially you're asking here if you should manually inline small functions rather than letting the compiler decide if/when to do that.  Under most circumstances, the answer to that question is "no."