# Place integer in buffer and left pad with zeroes?

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a protocol and currently have problems with this step:

```
The big-endian binary representation of the sequence number SHALL be placed in a 16-octet buffer and padded (on the left) with zeros.
```

The sequence number is an `int`.

I think the correct way to create the 16-octet buffer is like this:

```
buf := make([]byte, 16)
```

However, I'm not sure how to place the sequence number in the buffer so it follows the requirements above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int16 to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260107/int16-to-byte-array)

Comment: Check one of the answers here (not the accepted one) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260107/int16-to-byte-array

Comment: `binary.BigEndian.PutUint16` is close to what i need, but the zeros are not left padded. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Ok, check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836433/golang-add-int-to-end-of-byte-array -- somehow it looks to me that asking Google helps... Although I will admit that this is not ideal

Comment: Unfortunately, much Google searching has not revealed any solutions to my problem.

Comment: It's useless to downvote my question without providing a reason why. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
func seqToBuffer(seq int) []byte {
    buf := make([]byte, 16)
    for i := len(buf) - 1; seq != 0; i-- {
        buf[i] = byte(seq & 0xff)
        seq >>= 8
    }
    return buf
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I want. Is this the most simple way it can be done?

Comment: You can use one of the `binary.BigEndian.PutUint*`. You just need to pick a fixed size for the sequence number and write it to the appropriate place in the buffer. For example: `binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf[8:], uint64(seq))`